# Role Difference between StakeHolder and ProductOwner

Tags: scrum, scrum-master

What is actually the role difference between ProductOwner and StakeHolder ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A [stakeholder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stakeholder_%28corporate%29) is anyone that is potentially affected by the outcome of the project. The term is usually used to name the management or the customers.

The [product owner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29#Roles) is a stakeholder by defintion (just like the developers in fact), but is generally the person that represents the stakeholders (given the general usage described before).

When we say that stakeholders can assist to the daily scrums & reviews, it is because one of the biggest aim of Scrum is to put lot of *visibility* on what is being done. That increased visibility helps impediments to be identified & solved quickly. It also helps every party to understand each other's constraints & interests.

Answer (score 0):

While the Product Owner is affected by the outcome of the project, it generally NOT seen as a stakeholder. Scrum defines stakeholders as not part of the Scrum-team. The Product Owner is in fact part of the Scrum-team and therefore no stakeholder.

Comment: I agree. A stackholder can loosely be described as "someone who cares about how the product works". In that respect, a product owner doesn't care how it works. What they _do_ care about is whether the product meets the needs of the stakeholders. It doesn't matter to the product owner what those needs are, only that they are met. They aren't a stakeholder, but they are the _voice_ of the stakeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Product owner is responsible for creating and ordering the product backlog and to maximize the value of the product. product owner is a scrum team member.

On the other hand, according to scrum glossary, a stakeholder: a person external to the Scrum Team with a specific interest in and knowledge of a product that is required for incremental discovery. Represented by the Product Owner and actively engaged with the Scrum Team at Sprint Review.

Comment: This has already been addressed in other answers; please do not repeat answers on SE sites.

Comment: Well, I don't agree totally with the answers above, so I wrote my answer. I don't know why you @jan Doggen just voted -1 to my answer. Is there anything wrong in the answer so please chritisize? You shall give -1 if the answer is wrong.

Comment: I did not vote -1. There is nothing 'wrong' with the answer, but it does not contribute much - it seems to be quoting definitions from somewhere.